# Oracle Apex set value to page item DA

Tags: oracle-apex

In dynamic action, can we set value in this way?

Set type-> PL/SQL Expression

Expression   ->   :EMPLOYEE   (Column)

Affected Item->  :P1_EMP

Or the pl'sql expression needs to be a page item only?

Comment: Please provide as much info as possible. I'm assuming this is an interactive grid because of the syntax. What is it you want to do ? Set a default value or set value based on an event ?